# Which KVM supported OS to use for latest fedora?

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, fedora

On the latest CentOS which is 7.3 right now, the latest supported fedora in KVM is fedora 23.

If I want to have a Fedora 25 guest, which OS should I then say it is? Generic64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use the latest Fedora option - Fedora 23.